# Can not insert decimal greater than 1,000.00

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm using vb.net. I'm converting the value of my textbox to decimal with this code:

```
 textbox.text = string.format("{0:n2}", CType(textbox.text, Decimal))
```

The code is working and it converts it to decimal. But when the converted value is 1,000.00 or more and I insert it to database there's an error, [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9FRU.jpg).

> The datatype of column name in database is decimal (10,2)

Comment: remove comma first before inserting

Comment: try this `textbox.text = CType(textbox.text, Decimal).ToString("F2");`

Comment: *"im converting the value of my textbox to decimal with this code: textbox.text = string.format("{0:n2}", CType(textbox.text, Decimal))"*.  No you aren't!  You're converting the `String` to a `Decimal` and back to a `String` again.  If you want a number then use a number.  You don't need to format a number.  It's a number.

Comment: Jmchilhinney what im trying to do is when i input 1000 i wanted it to add 2 decimal places automatically and I used the code i written in the question. Any idea sir how can i do it other way

Comment: Metal i tried ur code and it add 2 decimal places too but i still get the same error. I think the error occur when the number has ' , '(comma). Maybe I should remove the comma first before inserting it in database. Any idea sir?

Comment: Hi jmchilhinney, i now know the answer because of your help. Thank you so much